# automatic rails app startup on server boot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

how can I make ruby on rails app start automatically on Mac OS X Server boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this an actual mac server with OS X server installed, or are you talking about your local development box?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend using [passenger](http://www.modrails.com/index.html), it makes all these headaches away. It even has an [OS-X control panel](http://github.com/alloy/passengerpane/tree/master), made my life a whole lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

ok, found the answer.

first create file in /Library/LaunchDaemons/my.startup.rails.app.plist

it's an xml file with a structure like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>my.startup.rails.app</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Library/WebServer/start.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>86400</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

where /Library/WebServer/start.sh contains shell script to launch the rails app.

Then make it launch when your computer boots:

sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/my.startup.rails.app.plist

Done!

Comment: You might want to look into using GOD to manage your rails processes.  More info here: http://ezinearticles.com/?Why-Rails-Developers-Need-God&id=845672

Comment: I also need solution for my El Capitan. my app in /Users/myuser/myapp and  I created start.sh left in  /Users/myuser/myapp. with following command cd /Users/myuser/myapp ; rails s but not work. Could you give some sample to start up / Thanks P Kul