# Boot rails when start up in El Capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, boot

This is the question extended from the same Title  here [automatic rails app startup on server boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1374732/automatic-rails-app-startup-on-server-boot)

I followed the answer of that link until the need to create start.sh

Don't know how to put rails s in start.sh properly

I tried

```
cd /Users/MyUser/myapp
rails s
```

or

```
/Users/MyUser/myapp/ rails s
```

After rebooted nothing happened (as expected to be able to brows localhost:3000)

Help need or any other solution. I also tried the passenger but already out dated no longer support in this El Capitan

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried nginx and passenger from homebrew?

Comment: not yet, will try and update later Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried both answers.

1. Using pow server would cost me for their tools to let public access my server.
2. The $PATH could be my problem. However if I login and run script it work.
3. I found an alternative solution which related Q with login my account and then set my Mac to auto login using [Running script upon login mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6442364/running-script-upon-login-mac)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your correct version if Ruby, and relevant gems are available in the $PATH environment variable of the script.

Comment: Yes, I still have $PATH issue of Warning! PATH is not pro.. I try to remove all ruby and install again but still. Unless I try as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17968580/warning-path-is-not-properly-set-up-usually-this-is-caused-by-shell-initializa . Which only temp for me.

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS you can use [pow server](http://pow.cx)